# Obtain Polish citizenship by starting a Polish business which is subcontracted by my US-based business?

Tags: immigration, poland, business

I am a US citizen, and my goal is to become a citizen of Poland. I intend to continue learning the language and culture and to integrate. I will speak with an immigration lawyer soon, but I am here to gather information prior to engaging with a lawyer.

From my research, I understand a foreigner can become a Polish citizen by investing in a business or by starting and investing in a business ([source](https://www.atozserwisplus.pl/blog/Citizenship-by-Investment-in-Poland)). From this article I understand one would follow these steps:

1. Apply for a short-term residence permit in order to stay in Poland for more than 90 days.
2. Invest 100,000 EUR in an existing, profitable business or start a business with a 100,000 EUR investment.
3. Open a business bank account in Poland.
4. Rent a flat and live there at least 10 months per year.
5. Apply for a permanent residence permit.
6. Learn the Polish language to a B1 level or greater.
7. Maintain profitability of the business, and ensure taxes are paid properly.
8. Live in Poland for at least 3 years.
9. Apply for citizenship by investment.

(Please feel free to correct me if any steps are incorrect or missing.)

I own an existing business in the US. To maintain my Polish business's profitability, can my US business simply subcontract work out to my Polish business?

Comment: You would probably want to work with a lawyer in Poland who specializes on this type of immigration cases.